# Passing an asterisk to a command-line program makes filenames appear in argv

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, argv

I am having really strange issue. I am passing multiple arguments in command line of my Objective-C program via the following commands.

```
gcc -framework Foundation main.m calculator.m -o prog1

./prog1 3 + 5 / 8
```

When I print `argc` and `argv[]` it gives me following output that is correct

```
argc = 6

argv[] = prog1,3,+,5,/,8
```

The problem occurs when I insert a "*" in the input: `./prog1 3 + 5 / 8 * 8` Then it gives me really strange output

```
argc = 12
argv [] = 3,+,5,/,8,calculator.h,calculator.m,main.m,prog1,8
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [The issue of \* in Command line argument](/q/2718873/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options

- Escape each single special symbol with a backslash (`\*`) or
- Double-quote the argument (as in `"*"`).

Answer (score 3):

The shell that you're running from is interpreting the asterisk as a [file glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)); it's replacing that character with the names of all the files in the current directory before passing the arguments to your program.

You need to escape the asterisk `\*` in order for it to be passed along literally. This also applies to other characters that your shell interprets, such as quote marks `"` and `'`, backslashes, and ampersands.